# Proportional editing excluding certain faces

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to scale part of a mesh using proportional editing, but certain faces aren't being affected despite them being well within the radius of the proportional editing circle.

Has anyone else encountered this? Am I forgetting something or doing something silly here?

For brevity, [here's the .blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q42TeqOX_WR8iv7dunnYNDWWmIaxkmih/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Are you in the right proportional editing mode? (Not "Random" or similiar.) Are you possibly using shapekeys?

Comment: I tried all of t hem. I  updated the original post to include my Blend file.

Comment: You have X-Mirror checked, uncheck it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case one can either edit the left or right side of the objects location. This is because **X Mirror** is active.

[image]

Disable it by pressing <kbd>T</kbd> to open the tools panel. Go to the **options** tab and uncheck X-Mirror.

For further reference, also make sure you're the "Apply shape in edit mode" option of shapekeys as that could change edit mode behaviour as well and you have chosen the correct [proportional editing mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/proportional_edit.html?highlight=proportional%20editing#object-mode).